# Internal energy of a gas

Tags: physical-chemistry

My professor says that the internal energy of a gas is the sum of its kinetic energy and potential energy: $U = E_k + E_p$.

It also says that the root-mean-square speed of gas molecules is $v_{rms}=\sqrt{\frac{3RT}{M}}$. Rearranging this formula gives: $E_k = 1/2*M*v_{rms}^2=3/2*R*T$.

Further, my textbook also says that the potential energy of an ideal gas is 0, because there are no attractive or repulsive forces in the gas.

Then, it seems as though the first equation becomes: $U = 3/2*R*T + 0 = 3/2*R*T$, but we know that the internal energy of an ideal gas is not always $U = 3/2*R*T$; it changes based on the state (constant temperature or constant pressure) and the geometry of the gas molecule (monatomic, diatomic, or nonlinear).

What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, internal energy of ideal gas changes with geometry of gas molecule, ig, it's $f/2 \, \,  nRT$ where $f$ is degree of freedom. For ideal gas internal energy is function of temperature alone, i.e. $f(T)$. Maxwell-Boltzman distribution

Comment: @Zenix I understand that the internal energy changes with geometry. However, what is wrong the "derivation" that U always = 3/2RT in my post?

Comment: U=3/2RT IS valid only for ideal monoatomic gas. For other ideal gasses, rotational and vibrational modes have to be included. For real gases, U=f(T) is not linear, mainly due vibration quantization.

Comment: You should distinguish between translational and vibrational KE.

Comment: @BuckThorn can't we ignore vibrational energy at low temperatures?

Comment: The factor $\ce{3/2}$ that you use in the expression of the internal energy, is only valid for rare gases. For diatomic molecules like $\ce{O_2}$ or $\ce{N_2}$, this factor is $\ce{5/2}$

Comment: The only intensive variable that affects the internal energy of an ideal gas is the temperature.  The pressure has no effect.   Thus, for *one mole of monatomic ideal gas*, your equation (U = 3/2 RT) is correct.  And, for the same reason, your statement that the internal energy "changes based on the state (constant temperature or constant pressure)" is *not* correct. You might be confusing internal energy with the heat capacity, which is dependent on the constraints (constant p vs constant V).

Comment: @theorist what is the internal energy of a diatomic ideal gas then? is it 5/2RT?

Comment: Yes.   A monatomic ideal gas has 3 translational degrees of freedom (x, y, and z), and thus has $U = 3/2 N k T = 3/2 nRT$ (where $N$ is the no. of particles, and $n$ is the no. of moles).   A diatomic ideal gas adds two rotational degrees of freedom (no chemical bonds, so no vibrational degrees of freedom), giving $U=5/2NkT=5/2nRT$.

Comment: @Maurice  The 5/2 factor only applies to real gases like $\ce{O_2}$ or $\ce{N_2}$ at low temperatures.   At higher temperatures, since they are real gases, you need to add the vibrational contribution.